# How to I dynamically generate a modal dialog on link click with bootstrap/adminlte?

Tags: html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, adminlte

I'm working on a little PHP/HTML project thats got me customising an AdminLTE template to use as a web dashboard.

I want to use the inbuilt bootstrap modal dialog functionality and have it so that when the user clicks a specific link, the modal is generated dynamically with content specific to that link.

So far I've been able to get the modal functionality working, but is in no way dynamic and I cant wrap my head around how to make it so (I'm usually a dev in .net/powershell etc and don't play around with this stuff too much, so pardon if my terminology isn't quite on point.)

In my page content, I'm generating the link like so (PHP querying MSSQL and building a HTML table)...

```
 if ($numrows){
            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        
            echo '  <tr>';
            echo '      <td>' . $row['did'] . '</td>';
            echo '      <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">' . $row['hostname'] . '</a></td>';
            //echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">';
            echo '      <td>' . $row['os'] . '</td>';
            echo '      <td><span class="badge bg-success">Online</span></td>';
            echo '    </tr>';
            
            }
        }
```

When the user clicks the link, the modal is activated from the #modal-default, which is defined on the same PHP page currently, like so...

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>One fine body...</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
```

So I'm guessing I need to have the link point elsewhere, perhaps to javascript or something that will reference a different PHP file to retrieve the content specific to that link before building the modal dynamically.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So after much playing around, I finally nailed this and wanted to share incase anyone else comes up against this...

I amended the link to include a class, like so...

```
  echo '<td><a class="loadmodalcontent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">' . $row['hostname'] . '</a></td>';
```

Then I added the following JS to the bottom of the ...

```
 <script>
 $('.loadmodalcontent').on('click',function(){
$('.modal-body').load('test.html',function(){
    $('#modal-default').modal({show:true});
});
});
</script>
```

The resulting behavior is that the modal is loaded and the contents of test.html is loaded into the modal-body.